# Update multiple workbooks through a macro in a single workbook

Tags: vba, excel, logic

Need suggestions on the logic to perform the objective illustrated in image below.

[image]

At the moment, my logic to perform the task start off with:

1. Loop through ID column in sheet1 of Book1
2. Set variable to corresponding row data, under column IDData1 & IDData2
3. (NESTED IF) IF ID = ID1, then open ID1to4 workbook
4. Once workbook is opened, call out another class that executes function.
5. Save & close workbook then go to next row & perform the same operation.

​​​​​​​Is there a better way than my current logic for it?

​​​​​​​P.S New to programming but kinda understand how it works...

Comment: Your plan is good under paper rules, meaning you prepare a record in advance of its being needed. Under electronic rules data are prepared when they are required and not before. Of course, Excel supports electronic rules much better than what you have in mind. If you want to use Excel's infrastructure you would enter formulas in your target workbooks which extract data from the source and update automatically when that workbook is opened. As an alternative to formulas you might use VBA doing the same job at the same time.

Comment: @Variatus I did think of the possibility of formula to execute them. Yup it can be done. But not exactly what I need. In excel Macro2 is recorded update the data above accordingly. Leaving Row 38 available for the next record

Comment: Don't open, save, or close within the loop. If in a second iteration you open, edit, and save the same file, you are not optimized. You need a nested loop for that function.

Comment: @MoondogsMaDawg What do you mean by optimize?

Comment: ID1 and ID2 affect the same workbook, right? But in your question, you open, save, and close on ID1 and ID2. That's a waste of time, memory, processing.... I'm not sure how helpful this is without code to troubleshoot. This seems like a Code Review question when you write the procedure.

Comment: What I mean is: don't worry if it's the best way. Just go write something and you will learn far more than we can type. If it doesn't work, bring it here. If it does and you want to improve it, take it to Code Review. Then do it over again.

Comment: My point is that, under paper rules, you create a journal and post to the ledger. Under database rules you create each ledger account from the database as and when you need it. Hence you think of updating a specific workbook when you enter something in row 38, 39 and 40. My recommendation is to think of updating the specific workbook only when someone wants to look at it, of course, including rows 38, 39 and 40. Whether you do it by macro or worksheet function is immaterial.

Comment: In your way of thinking the journal is expandable because all details have been posted to the workbooks. I suggest to make the workbooks expandable because you can recreate them from the journal. In fact, if you plan to be able to recreate them from the journal their very existence takes on a different meaning. Just imagine, when you go online and view your bank statement. What you get to see is an excerpt from a database created on the fly for this occasion, with up-to-the-minute data, to be destroyed when you close your browser.